# When app returns to foreground async main_queue calls not performed until after expiration handler

Tags: objective-c, queue, grand-central-dispatch, foreground

I've a task that renders e.g. 50 objects and saves each one as a file. It's set up to continue running in the background and notify the user when the task is completed. While in the foreground, there's a progress bar, that shows the user how far along everything is.

The rendering & writing of files are all done on custom background threads, using GCD. In order to update the progress bar, dispatch_async on the main_queue is called.

---

### Here's my problem...

When the user enters the background, the task continues as planned and, if let alone and still in the background, notifies the user when it's complete. But if the user returns sooner, and the app is still rendering/writing, I/the user would expect to see the progress and all >>> That does not happen. Even though my method to update the progress bar is sent off via dispatch_async on main_queue, the task isn't executed (or the main_queue received if you will), until the 'renter/writing' task I sent in the background is completed and the ExpirationHandler performed.

In the 'applicationWillEnterForeground:' method I tell the app, that it should 'endBackgroundTask:' and set the instance (=self.backgroundTask) to 'UIBackgroundTaskInvalid', but that doesn't make a difference

### My question...

Is there a way for me to get back control of a task (running on a GCD-custom background thread) that I sent into the background (beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:) when the app closed?

AND/OR

Do I not specifically have to get back control, but do/set something differently?

Comment: Is your app still responsive when brought back to the foreground?  i.e. do UI elements respond etc?  I'm curious if you're somehow blocking the main runloop/queue.

Comment: hey wade, thanks for your response! I can't say for sure, since it's an initial-load screen, which isn't meant to be interacted with. It's possible, that the main thread is locked, but I should point out that if I don't close the app, everything works fine.

Comment: Right, but I'm wondering if something is happening as a result of going into or out of the background, that delays the main thread.  Seemingly something that unsticks when your expiration handler fires.  It might be worth just throwing a button+label or something similarly trivial into your app, that you can press and see a result.  Just to confirm.  But I am throwing guesses out here.

Comment: hey wade, thanks -- I'll check that. I do think, that something is blocking the main queue.

Comment: Hi, In my experience I ended up having to do the UI updates with KVO on the main thread; something like watching for myBackgroundObject.hasUpdate=YES and then reading the object's properties to update a progress bar. But it wasn't perfect, for instance trying to performSelector:afterDelay: within the main threads observation method had to be replaced with an NSTimer because it just wouldn't fire. And stopping a background task could only be done by setting a myBackgroundObject.isCancelled=YES and just having the main background loop check for it - all IMHO